# Help with Markov's inequality

Tags: probability

We have 2 7-sided dice. The first die is a normal fair die where each face has a probability of showing of $1/7$. However, the second die is rigged so that the probability of showing the largest face (7) is twice as high as of the other faces and all of the other faces have equal probabilities.

What is the expected value of the outcome from tossing the fair die? 
What is the expected value of the outcome from tossingthe rigged die?

We throw the fair die 2 times, then the rigged die 5 times consecutively and sum up all the outcomes:
What is the expected value of the sum? Let Y denote the sum from the previous part. If we know that

$P(Y>k)≤0.1$

According to Markov’s inequality, what is $k$?

I am confused on how to do this problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what have you tried? Can you not even work out the expected value of a fair die or a rigged die for a start? also what is markov's inequality?

Answer (score 0):

Let X be the event of tossing a fair die and getting one of the faces.  $P(X=k)=\frac1{7}, k=1..7$.  The expected outcome of tossing the fair die is 
$$E(X)=\sum_{k=1}^7kP(X=k)=\sum_{k=1}^7k\frac1{7}=\frac{7\cdot8}{2\cdot7}=4$$
Let Z be the event of tossing a weighted die whose largest valued face has a probability of being tossed twice that of each lower valued face.  $P(X=k)=\frac1{8}, k=1..6,$ and $P(X=7)=\frac1{4}$.  Why?  Because the 7 has double the chances.  Think of a jar and there are 2 7-balls in there and 1 1-6 balls.  The sample space would therefore be $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7\}$.  The the expected outcome of tossing the weighed dice is
$$E(X)=\sum_{k=1}^7kP(X=k)=\sum_{k=1}^6k\frac1{8}+7\cdot\frac1{4}=\frac{6\cdot7}{2\cdot8}+\frac{14}{4}=\frac{49}{8}=6.125$$
Now, let Y be the event of tossing a fair die twice and the rigged die 5 times.  Then $$Y=2X+5Z$$
The expected value, found by linearity of the Expected value operator, is 
$$E(Y)=E(2X+5Z)=E(2X)+E(5Z)=2E(X)+5E(Z)$$
$$E(Y)=2\cdot4+5\cdot6.125=8+30.625=38.625$$
Finally the Markov inequality indicates that for some value $k$,
$$P(Y\gt{k})\le\frac{E(Y)}{k}$$
You're given that $\frac{E(Y)}{k}=.1$